# What does is mean to center variables?

Tags: matrices, covariance, correlation, transpose

I was reading [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/240967) that is talking about properties of $AA^T$.

> If you *center* columns (variables) of $\bf A$, then $\bf A'A$ is the
> **scatter** (or co-scatter, if to be rigorous) matrix and $\mathbf {A'A}/(n-1)$ is the **covariance** matrix. Pairwise formula of
> covariance is $\frac{\sum c_xc_y}{n-1}$ with $c_x$ and $c_y$ denoting
> centerted columns.

The answer didn't provide any definition of *centering* here. I have some guesses that it means to subtract the mean of each column from itself, but because I'm not a mathematician I'm afraid that my guess is wrong. So I'm here to make sure the correct definition.

Comment: sounds correct to me :-)